# How to get the destiny beta nameplate?

Tags: destiny

In the beta you were supposed to receive an nameplate if you played at 2:00 pm PDT. I got a message saying public event and clicked it but received no nameplate. Do I not get it until the full game or has my game glitched and I just can't get it.

Comment: See also: [Is there a way to check whether I unlocked the Destiny nameplate?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/178229/30863)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You do not receive this nameplate until you purchase the game when it is released.

Quote from the [Bungie Weekly Update - 07/25/2014](http://www.bungie.net/7_Bungie-Weekly-Update---07252014/en/News/News?aid=11963)

> Everyone who makes an appearance will earn a nameplate to help you prove that you were there when the record for concurrent players was set before the launch of the game. It will help you to be a rare and unique snowflake *when Destiny launches in September.*

This is what it will look like:

[image: Beta Nameplate]