# Is there a way to check whether I unlocked the Destiny nameplate?

Tags: destiny

I played the destiny beta at 2pm and 5pm. I didn't play the event, I didn't know it was going on. I was signed in and just messed around in old Russia.

Do I get a nameplate or any reward?

Comment: Not quite a duplicate: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/178180/336

Comment: I am nominating this question for reopening because this isn't a duplicate. The other question is asking _how_ to get the nameplate, this question is asking _if they did_ get the nameplate.

Comment: I didn't receive any notification during the beta, and thought I'd missed this - however on playing the release version as @Eben mentions below I had the nameplate waiting for me at the Postmaster/Special Order vendor.

Answer (score 2):

I'm fairly sure the only way to know is to log into the game. If you got the nameplate it will either be in your inventory or at the Special Order vendor.

Comment: Mine was delivered at the Special Order vendor.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Eben, the nameplate should initially be in your inventory, or delivered via a special order, when you first log into the game. It is also possible, however, that you unlocked the emblem at an earlier date, and since dropped or removed it from your inventory.

With the release of The Taken King, you will find access to an [Emblem Collection](http://db.destinytracker.com/vendors/3301500998-emblem-collection), where you will be able to retrieve any unlocked emblems. This includes the [Sign of the Elders](http://db.destinytracker.com/items/1409854025-sign-of-the-elders) emblem.